# Get last 14 days in reverse order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print stats for each of the last 14 days in the view.

For that I'm aiming to create a range of dates, starting with today and ending with the 14th day (back in time), to iterate over with an `.each` in the view.

```
most_recent   = Date.current
least_recent  = Date.current.ago(14.days)
```

This doesn't work:

```
most_recent..least_recent.each
```

And this doesn't seem to work:

```
(most_recent).downto(least_recent).each
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
14.times do |i|
  date = Date.today-i
  #do stuff with date
end
```

Comment: Stefan's answer is more elegant :-)

Answer (score 8):

I'd use [`Numeric#ago`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-ago):

```
14.downto(0) do |i|
  date = i.days.ago
end
```

You attempts didn't work because `most_recent` is larger than `least_recent` (I'm using integers here, but it's the same for dates):

```
(0..-14).to_a      #=> []
-14.downto(0).to_a #=> []
```

These methods only work "from low to high":

```
(-14..0).to_a      #=> [-14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0]
0.downto(-14).to_a #=> [-14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0]
```

Comment: i've not used `days.ago` in the past because I read it has a higher server overhead - or is that only the case for `time_ago_in_words`?

Comment: @Stefan Is this a Rails method? :)

Comment: @dax it doesn't have any overhead. `14.days` returns `1209600` (number of seconds) and `1209600.ago` simply returns `Time.current - 1209600`

Comment: @Stefan Sorry! I didn't see the link you have provided.. :)

Answer (score 5):

How is this using [**`Date#downto`**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-downto)?

```
require 'date'

dt = Date.today
dt.downto(dt-5){|d| puts d }
```

output:

```
2013-09-27
2013-09-26
2013-09-25
2013-09-24
2013-09-23
2013-09-22
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [step method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-step); stepping with -1 goes back in time.

```
require 'date'
most_recent = Date.today
least_recent = most_recent - 14
most_recent.step(least_recent, -1){|d| puts d}
#=> 2013-09-27
#=> 2013-09-26
#=> 2013-09-25
#=> 2013-09-24
#=> 2013-09-23 
#=> ...
```

Comment: `downto(min){|date| ...}` is equivalent to `step(min, -1){|date| …}` :) But I like your approach to... :) So you have mine.. *+1*..

Answer (score 0):

```
((Date.today - 14)...(Date.today)).reverse_each do |d|
  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE.. puts d
end
```

Comment: You have to `reverse` the array: *"starting with today and ending with the 14th day"*

Comment: Ahh.. I missed that .. I will do it now .. Thanx

Comment: Yeah I am going for the same.. :)

Comment: You can do what I put in the comment,as we have [**Enumerable#reverse_each**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each)

Comment: Thats great.. its working .. no need to do to_a on that.. Thanks @ArupRakshit

Comment: You got my one too for the same... :) Enjoy Ruby !!

Comment: @BachanSmruty maybe you should explain why it works this way (`least_recent..most_recent`) and not the other (`most_recent..least_recent`).

Comment: Be careful with the `...` operator. It is seldom used because it's misunderstood or not even know by many due to it being unintuitive. Combine that with `reverse_each` and your code becomes more obscure which can lead to bugs being introduced when someone has to maintain it. It's like a sentence with double-negatives, it works but deciphering it can make our brains spin.